# Updating a Table in sql

Tags: c#, sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE InsertHash
    @FileName varchar(max),
    @Hash  varchar(max)
AS
UPDATE tabletest 
SET deneme1 = @Hash, deneme2 =@FileName
```

this is my stored procedure, and i send some data

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    string filename = @"\\" + rdr.GetString(3);
    filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(filename, rdr.GetString(2));
    filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(filename, rdr.GetString(1));
    computeHashh1 abc = new computeHashh1();
    Console.WriteLine(abc.computeHash(filename));
    SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand("InsertHash", myConnection);
    myCommand2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@FileName", filename);
    myCommand2.Parameters.Add(param);
    SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@Hash", abc.computeHash(filename));
    myCommand2.Parameters.Add(param2);
}
```

its not updating the table when i run the code, what can be the problem, sory for such bad question im quite new to sql

Comment: Beware! How many records are supposed to be in that table? Your stored procedure without a where clause will update everything.

Comment: @levanlevi I think everything we need is already there...

Comment: I meant connection opening, executing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one thing you **don't** with with `myCommand2` is... execute it:

```
myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

well, actually you should dispose it too...

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    // ... blah
    using(var myCommand2 = new SqlCommand("InsertHash", myConnection))
    {
        // setup parameters etc
        myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Or if that seems too much work... some "dapper" love:

```
myConnection.Execute("InsertHash", new {
        FileName = filename,
        Hash = abc.computeHash(filename)
    }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Comment: i'm taking this error : There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Comment: @tipi yes, normally (unless MARS is enabled) you can't execute another command while a reader is open. This usually means buffering the data first, for example: read all the data into a *list*, then enumerate the list (now the reader is closed) doing other things. Be cautious of N+1, though

Answer (score 3):

You haven't executed the command:

```
myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```